# Solving a problem recursively regarding access to certain elements of an infinite list

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

My problem itself is not important at all, but I will state it so you can understand what essentially I'm trying to understand.

Nicomano said that you can calculate the cube of a natural number m like this:

for m=1, take the first odd number, sum them, and that is the cube (1^3 = 1)

for m=2, take the two next odds numbers,sum them, and that is the cube (2^3 = 3 + 5)

for m=3, take the three next odds numbers, sum them, and that is the cube (3^3 = 7 + 9 + 11)

And so on.

Solving this is easy just like this

```
--first we create an infinite odd list
odds :: [Integer]
odds = [i | i<-[1..], not (even i)]

--now the function 
nicomano :: Int -> Integer
nicomano m = sum (take m (drop (sum[1..(m-1)]) odds))
```

Problem is, if I want to solve this recursively. When I try to do this, I ask myself the relation (mathematically speaking) between one `nicomano m` iteration and the previous one `nicomano m-1`.

The relation I found is the following one:

`nicomano m = take (sum [1..m]) odds - (nicomano(1)+nicomano(2)+...+nicomano(m-1))`

But this won't work to find a recursive solution, as I need the previous values of nicomano function for calculating the `nicomano(m)` one, and Haskell doesn't allow saving values in a list like in Python for example. Also If I could do it, it wouldn't be a recursive solution.

So how could we do this? Isn't it a good approach for finding recursive solutions to ask yourself about the relationship between one step and another?

Comment: "Haskell doesn't allow saving values in a list" This is of course completely untrue but irrelevant. You don't need to sum all odd numbers from 1 up to the desired one and then subtract, you just need to sum up the interval you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current function `Int -> Integer` is just `f m = m ** 3`, and there's no nice recurrence to exploit in the nicomano manner.

Instead, I would suggest you build a function to generate the list of odds for the respective step:

```
nicomano :: Int -> [Integer]
nicomano 0 = [1, 3..]
nicomano n = drop n $ nicomano $ n - 1

cube :: Int -> Integer
cube n = sum $ take n $ nicomano $ n - 1
```

You might also find a tail-recursive formulation of this, but I think that's more ugly.

Another approach, specially suited for lazy evaluation of Haskell, is building an infinite sequence:

```
cube :: Int -> Integer
cube = \n -> cubes !! n
  where
    cubes = nicomano 0 [1, 3..]
    nicomano i odds = let (begin, rest) = splitAt i odds
                      in sum begin : nicomano (i+1) rest
```